# How to I get a specific part of an element when clicking anywhere in that element with Vanilla Javascript (NO JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get from the following html "only" the number 0 or the number 1 depending on which table row I click (FYI: there will be many rows with different numbers):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../static/js/test.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody id="toAppend">
      <tr class="newEle" onclick="setUnstakeNumber()">
        <th>
          "Stake No"
          <div class="d-inline-block"></div>
        </th>
          <td class="p3 unstakeIdx">0</td>
          <td class="p3">Joo: 1</td>
          <td class="p3">9/22/2022, 5:02:30</td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="newEle" onclick="setUnstakeNumber()">
        <th>
          "Stake No"
          <div class="d-inline-block"></div>
        </th>
          <td class="p3 unstakeIdx">1</td>
          <td class="p3">Joo: 2</td>
          <td class="p3">9/22/2022, 5:04:18</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks visually:

[image]

This is how the html looks in console view:

[image]

This is my javascript function:

```
function setUnstakeNumber() {
  let selection = document.getSelection();
  let finalSelection = selection.anchorNode.data
  let activeTextarea = document.activeElement;
  let parent = document.documentElement.parentElement; // Returns the <html> element 
  console.log(selection);
  console.log(finalSelection);
  console.log(parent);
  console.log(activeTextarea);
}
```

But none of the above works.

The closest one is the finalSelection, but I need to really click exactly on top of the number I want rather then anywhere in its row.

How do I get the number by clicking anywhere in its element?

So If I would click anywhere in the first row I would get the number 0 and if I would click anywhere in the second row I would get the number 1 with only Vanilla Javascript (No JQuery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```js
function setUnstakeNumber() {
let selection = document.getSelection();
// get selected row
let selectedRow = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.parentNode;   
let index = selectedRow.childNodes[3].innerText;
console.log(index);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../static/js/test.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <table>
    <tbody id="toAppend">
      <tr class="newEle" onclick="setUnstakeNumber()">
        <th>
          "Stake No"
          <div class="d-inline-block"></div>
        </th>
          <td class="p3 unstakeIdx">0</td>
          <td class="p3">Joo: 1</td>
          <td class="p3">9/22/2022, 5:02:30</td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="newEle" onclick="setUnstakeNumber()">
        <th>
          "Stake No"
          <div class="d-inline-block"></div>
        </th>
          <td class="p3 unstakeIdx">1</td>
          <td class="p3">Joo: 2</td>
          <td class="p3">9/22/2022, 5:04:18</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

First get the selected row and then select the  which includes the index.